# Decryption in spring-ws (wss4j) without SoapAction header?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-security, spring-ws

my main issue is this:

When the soap message is encrypted, the `PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping` is unable to map the soap message because The security interceptor did not have yet the time to decipher it. The solution is to replace `@PayloadRoot` with `@SoapAction`.

When a soap message is received, spring-ws calls first the `PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping` then `SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping`

```
@Endpoint
public class assignedSubscriberNumberNotify {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://test.aek.seavus.com/";

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "ToOperatorChangeInASSNNotify")
    @SoapAction("http://www.test.si/toOperatorChangeInASSNNotify")
    @ResponsePayload
    public void toOperatorChangeInASSNNotify(@RequestPayload ToOperatorChangeInASSNNotify request){

    }
}
```

How can I decrypt request if client is unable to add SoapAction to the header?

tnx
miha

Comment: Why would a client be unable to add the SOAP-Action header? The fact that that SOAP Action needs to be specified is part of your WSDL and thus your contract. If a client doesn't send the header it doesn't comply with your contract.

Comment: The main issue is that we are doing integration with them. They can not change anything, the only option they have is to add our url to soap service. Wsdl files for generating classes we got from them. I added soapaction to soap files but they will not read them, they just use our URL to service and that is all. They can not do any modification (guverment thing). Everything must be done by us. When we send request to their service we also do not send them SoapAction. So is there any way to find a solution for this and spring will be able to decrypte request before @Endpoint?

Comment: Your comment doesn't make any sense... They are calling you, so there is a contract already, they should follow as well as you should. If encryption isn't part of the contract you cannot add encryption.

Comment: I asked them why they are not sending SoapAciton if I defined it in wsdl and I got answer that only URL can be added for our service. (they defined what we must implement)
 
I know what you are trying to say but I can not do much. So is there any option that request is decrypted without SoapAction header?

Comment: @M.Deinum or is there any way to trick spring so that Wss4jSecurityInterceptor triggered before PayloadRoot is searched?

Comment: So in doc there is written: Interceptors must implement the EndpointInterceptor interface from the org.springframework.ws.server package. This interface defines three methods, one that can be used for handling the request message before the actual endpoint will be executed.... I tried with handleRequest method but still it is triggered after Paylooadroot in Endpoint is searched

Comment: You don't understand the flow. It first needs to determine which endpoint to handle, before the request will be actually handled and decoded. So before it will invoke the interceptor it will need to detect the handler, with an encrypted message that isn't possible because it doesn't know the payload.

Comment: ok, thank you for explenation. But is there any other way to fix this? could this be solved by some trick? We are also not sending them with SoapAction and they are able to decode request.

Comment: @M.Deinum do you think there is a way to solve this? tnx

Comment: Just had the same issue with Spring-WS (unable to decrypt before Endpoint-Mapping), our solution was to use Spring with CXF directly. There it works with no problems.

Comment: @beat thank you for this information! Do you maybe have any example how to do decryption with spring + cfx? I was just using spring and do not have any expirance with cfx. tnx

Comment: @MihaZoubek as a starter you may use https://www.baeldung.com/apache-cxf-with-spring (no decryption). Then you need to add WSS4JOutInterceptor and WSS4JInInterceptor as can be seen here: https://github.com/JuanMorenoDeveloper/ws-security-spring-boot-cxf/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/proitc/wss/configuration/WebServiceConfiguration.java

Comment: Note: the example given in the last link is just a starting point, you will need to adapt the properties (for example set ConfigurationConstants.ACTION to ENCRYPT or the needed combination).

Comment: @beat I am speening here still for a while. As as this is for decryption i use WSS4JInInterceptor and then I use ACTION ENCRYPT. which propertis need to be set so that request be be decrypted properly? thank you!

Comment: @MihaZoubek really depends a bit on what you need. You might start using ConfigurationConstants.DEC_PROP_FILE and configure a merlin property file. There you specify your keystore and password.

Comment: @beat this is what i am trying to do. I have set "wss4JInInterceptor.setProperty(ConfigurationConstants.DEC_PROP_FILE, "myCrypto.properties");" but problem is that it does not read this file. I have put in resources. If I change the name of file to something i do not get any error regarding reading. Attaching link to pastebin how my config and propersties file looks like: https://pastebin.com/DK719iUD

Comment: @MIhaZoubek you should open a new question with more details in it

Comment: @beat done. i have opened new question with more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64677324/a-security-error-was-encountered-when-verifying-the-message-error-reading-xmlst